# React: Access element's text

Tags: javascript, reactjs

My component is used inside other render() like

```
return (<MyElem>Some text here</MyElem>)
```

How can I access the "Some text here" string inside my component's class?

Comment: What do you want to achieve?

Comment: I'd wanted not to add text as a property `<MyElem text="Some text here"></MyElem>` but to use it as a child text element `<MyElem>Some text here</MyElem>` because of ability to add inside the MyElem some children tags not just strings. I don't know is it okay or not

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You use the [`children` property](https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#children-in-jsx), which contains the children of your element (which might be text or an array of children [I *think* it's always an array when it's not text], see the link for the gory details). E.g.:

```js
const Foo = props => {
  console.log(props.children);
  return (
    <div>{props.children}</div>
  );
};
ReactDOM.render(
  <Foo>Hi There</Foo>,
  document.getElementById("react")
);
```

```html
<div id="react"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

That uses a stateless functional component (SFC), but it's the same for `Component` subclasses:

```js
class Foo extends React.Component {
  render() {
    console.log(this.props.children);
    return (
      <div>{this.props.children}</div>
    );
  }
};
ReactDOM.render(
  <Foo>Hi There</Foo>,
  document.getElementById("react")
);
```

```html
<div id="react"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

Here's an example of the fact that `children` isn't just for text:

```js
class Foo extends React.Component {
  render() {
    console.log(this.props.children);
    return (
      <div>{this.props.children}</div>
    );
  }
};
ReactDOM.render(
  <Foo>
    <div>Hi there</div>
    <Foo><span>nested Foo > Foo > span</span></Foo>
  </Foo>,
  document.getElementById("react")
);
```

```html
<div id="react"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: React's `children` prop will get you more than just text. It's worth noting that it's not equivalent to `element.innerText` or even `element.innerHTML`.

Comment: @gfullam - Well, I never said it was just text or equivalent to `innerText` or `innerHTML`, but I've updated to emphasize that it's not just text. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Add a ref to To MyElem:

```
<MyElem ref="elem">My text here<MyElem>
```

Then you can refer to your element elsewhere with:

```
this.refs.elem
```